# Get specific string after specific character

Tags: c#, string, char

I have a few string:

1. `<img title=\"\\angle X &lt; \\angle Y &lt; \\angle Z\" src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\angle&amp;space;X&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Y&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Z\" />`

I want to get `angle&amp;space;X&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Y&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Z`

and

2. `<img title=\"1,25 - \\frac{5}{6} \\times 280\\% \\div 1\\tfrac{1}{6}\" src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?1,25&amp;space;-&amp;space;\\frac{5}{6}&amp;space;\\times&amp;space;280\\%&amp;space;\\div&amp;space;1\\tfrac{1}{6}\" />`

I want to get:

```
frac{5}{6}&amp;space;\\times&amp;space;280\\%&amp;space;\\div&amp;space;1\\tfrac{1}{6}
```

Code:

```
string imgSoal;
string imgName = imgSoal.Split("\\")[1];
```

I'm having a problem, i.e. the string that I got from the above code are `angle&amp;space;X&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;` and `frac{5}{6}&amp;space;` How to get string i want (`angle&amp;space;X&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Y&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Z` and `frac{5}{6}&amp;space;\\times&amp;space;280\\%&amp;space;\\div&amp;space;1\\tfrac{1}{6}`)?

Comment: Are you saying you want to ignore the `\\` in double quotes, but then get the text after the first non-quoted `\\`?

Comment: inside scr=  and after the first double quote and before \" />

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IndexOf` method to get the first occurrence of the `\\` (inputChar) and then get the remaining string by using the `SubString` method.

```
var result = str.Substring(str.IndexOf(inputChar) + 1);
```

You need the handle the case if the given character is not present in the given string.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the string is incomplete. I have edited the string in the code above

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, the better way is create Regex to match the string that your want then remove unrelated character. I have implement the follow code please check.

```
private string stringA = "<img title=\"\\angle X &lt; \\angle Y &lt; \\angle Z\" src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\\angle&amp;space;X&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Y&amp;space;&lt;&amp;space;\\angle&amp;space;Z\" />";
private string stringB = "<img title=\"1,25 - \\frac{5}{6} \\times 280\\% \\div 1\\tfrac{1}{6}\" src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?1,25&amp;space;-&amp;space;\\frac{5}{6}&amp;space;\\times&amp;space;280\\%&amp;space;\\div&amp;space;1\\tfrac{1}{6}\" />";
private string patternA = @"\?(.*?)/>";
private string patternB = @";\\frac(.*?)/>";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(stringA, patternA))
{

    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    var tem = match.Value.Remove(0, 2);
    var res = tem.Substring(0, tem.Length - 4);
}
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(stringB, patternB))
{

    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
    var tem = match.Value.Remove(0, 2);
    var res = tem.Substring(0, tem.Length - 4);
}
```